# Sideloading only necessary data in ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Here are my model definitions:

```
var model = DS.Model,
    attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany;

App.Genre = model.extend({
    animes: hasMany('anime', {async: true}),
    nom: attr('string')
});
App.Anime = model.extend({
    nom: attr('string'),
    parution: attr('number'),
    synopsis: attr('string'),
    likes: attr('number'),
    auteur: attr('string'),

    genres: hasMany('genre', {async: true})
});
```

as shown in here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakoyipo/3/edit

when I access http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakoyipo/3#/animes for example.. all the `genres` gets loaded.. same thing when accessing http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakoyipo/3#/animes/1

so my question is: how to load only necessary data using ember-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. Take a look at http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakoyipo/12#/animes I removed the mockjax for genres, in your console you'll see it tries to get emberjs.jsbin.com/api/fr/genres?ids[]=1&ids[]=3. Because ember needs multiple genres it will not request emberjs.jsbin.com/api/fr/genres/1 and emberjs.jsbin.com/api/fr/genres/3 but requests both records in one call.

Comment: I read here something about this: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findMany